# Change default font of the app

Tags: android, fonts

I am working on an android project and I want to change default font for all the app, not just a single TextView or button.

My custom font is stored as `assets/fonts/font.ttf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Calligraphy library! It is completely designed for this problem.

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

From the documentation:

In a class extending `Application` put this code.

```
CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/font.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build()
        );
```

And then in each `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is: First create typeface object like this one:

```
Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/font.ttf");
```

and set this typeface wherever required like:

```
textView.setTypeFace(typeFace);
```

You can't change the font of whole app by just putting your font file in assets.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to deal with this before. its very annoying because there is no good way. the best way i have found it so override textview and use that custom class instead. make this class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by shemesht on 6/3/15.
 */
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeFace);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeFace);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeFace);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        Typeface typeFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttf");
        setTypeface(typeFace);
    }
}
```

and then in your xml just put

```
<com.yourApp.Namehere.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this text has a new font!"/>
```

Thats it. you can still just reference your textview as normal inside your java